# Why didn't draw concentric circles , but draw a growing circle?

Tags: processing

I want to draw concentric circles , so I write the code below

```
int radius = 30;

void setup(){
  size(1000,500);
  background(255,255,255); 
}

void draw(){
  ellipse(500,250,radius,radius);
  radius ++;
}
```

but the result are not concentric circles but a expanding circle

why it appear this result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `fill` setting is drawing over previous circles. Do you want to achieve this?

```
int radius = 30;
size(1000, 500);
background(255, 255, 255); 
noFill();

for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
  ellipse(500, 250, radius, radius);
  radius += 10;
}
```

Comment: Those are concentric. Try it with `radius += 10;` and you'll see

Comment: but only a circle display in the screen , but I expect several circles with different radius ..

Comment: Do you want a static display (showing lots of circles at once) or a dynamic display (plotting new bigger circles every frame)?

Comment: So I think you're looking for something like the new code above

Answer (score 2):

You don't see the smaller circle because the bigger one is on top hiding the previous one. The solution is to use a transparent fill with noFill()

```
int radius = 30;

void setup(){
  size(1000,500);
  background(255,255,255); 
}

void draw(){
  noFill();
  ellipse(500,250,radius,radius);
  radius ++;
}
```

Make the radius increment bigger (10) you to see the circles better

```
int radius = 30;

void setup(){
  size(1000,500);
  background(255,255,255); 
}

void draw(){
  noFill();
  ellipse(500,250,radius,radius);
  radius +=10;
}
```